# Android PowerManager

Tags: java, android

Такой вопрос. Использую данный код для пробуждения смартфона.

```java
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Проблема в том, что после включения дисплея, подсветка не гаснет автоматически, а экран будет гореть пока пользователь вручную не заблокирует экран. Можно ли как то на это повлиять. Быть может в момент вызова   `wakeLock.acquire();` програма берет управление на себя, и потом система не может до него достучаться, или как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вызвать `wakeLock.release()`.
Согласно [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) произойдет освобождение блокировки `wakeLock` после окончания работы приложения (вашей задачи) и предотвратится разрядка батареи.

Comment: Отлично, помогло, спасибо большое! Хорошего вам дня :)